# Finding the antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration

Let 
$$
\int {\frac{{1 + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}}{{{x^2} - 1 + \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}}}} dx
$$

I've been told use the substitution: $t = {{x-1} \over x}$.
But how to apply it on the integral?

Comment: The substitution should be $t=x-\frac 1x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^2-1+\frac1{x^2}=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+1$$

and since

$$\left(x-\frac1x\right)'=1+\frac1{x^2}$$

we get

$$\int\frac{1+\frac1{x^2}}{1+\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2}dx=\int\frac{\left(x-\frac1x\right)'dx}{1+\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2}=\arctan\left(x-\frac1x\right)+C$$

by the *almost* automatic integral

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}dx=\arctan f(x)+C$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $t=x-\frac 1x$ so that you get $dt=1+\frac 1{x^2}$. Then you have the integral as $$\int \frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\tan^{-1}t+C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 - 1 + {1\over x^2} = \left(x-{1\over x}\right)^2 + 1$$

Let $$\left(x-{1\over x}\right) = z $$

$$ \implies 1 + 1/x^2 dx = dz$$
So integral becomes

$$\int {dz \over z^2 + 1} $$

$$ = \arctan(z)$$
$$ = \arctan\left(x-{1\over x}\right) + C$$ Ans.